# How to download file from a page using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am having troubles downloading txt file from this page: https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data#RegulationEnergy (when you scroll down and see Download: txt, xls and xml).

My goal is to create scraper that will go to the linked page, clicks on the txt link for example and saves a downloaded file.

Main problems that I am not sure how to solve:

- The file doesn't have a real link that I can call and download it, but the link is created with JS based on filters and file type.
- When I use `requests` library for python and call the link with all headers it just redirects me to https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data .

Approaches tried:

- Using scraper such as ParseHub to download link didn't work as intended. But this scraper was the closest to what I've wanted to get.
- Used `requests` library to connect to the link using headers that HXR request uses for downloading the file but it just redirects me to https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data .

If you could propose some solution for this task, thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can download this data to a directory of your choice with Selenium; you just need to specify the directory to which the data will be saved. In what follows below, I'll save the txt data to my desktop:

```
from selenium import webdriver

download_dir = '/Users/doug/Desktop/'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : download_dir}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data')

container = driver.find_element_by_class_name('download-graph-data')
button = container.find_element_by_tag_name('li')
button.click()
```

Comment: Hi @duhaime good solution, can you tell me way to read html content through selenium ?

Comment: @NagaKiran Sure thing, using the code above, we'd call `driver.page_source` - that will return the HTML for the current page. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should do like so:

```py
import requests

txt_format = 'txt'
xls_format = 'xls' # open in binary mode
xml_format = 'xlm' # open in binary mode

def download(file_type):
    url = f'https://www.ceps.cz/download-data/?format={txt_format}'

    response = requests.get(url)

    if file_type is txt_format:
        with open(f'file.{file_type}', 'w') as file:
            file.write(response.text)
    else:
        with open(f'file.{file_type}', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)

download(txt_format)
```

Comment: You should open the file in `wb` mode and write `response.content`.

Comment: Since he wants to download a _txt file_ and response.text is _str_ type it's preferred to open it in _'w'_ mode

Comment: But for the xls and xml files?

Comment: In that case 'wb' mode. I added those variables just to let him know how to implement it. However, I'll edit the answer thank you!